# R function working with scalar input, but not working with vector input

Tags: r, function, loops

I am running the following function:

```
ll = function(b){
  o = numeric(length(d))
  l = numeric(length(d))
  
  for (i in 1:length(d)) {
    for (j in 1:nrow(a)) {
      if (a[j,1]>=d[i]){
        if (a[j,3]==1){
          o[i] = o[i] + 1
          
        }
        else {
          o[i] = o[i] + exp(b)
          
        }
      }
      if (a[which(a[,1]==d[i]),3] == 1) {
        l[i] = 1/o[i]
    }
      else {
        l[i] = exp(b)/o[i]
    }
    }
  }
  return(sum(log(l)))
}
```

`d` is a numeric vector and `a` is a 3 column data frame with the columns as numeric, 0 or 1, 0 or 1. They are both outside the function.

Now this function is working fine (I think) with single inputs, but not with vector inputs. So:

```
ll(cox.fit$coefficients)
```

seems to work fine but

```
sq = seq(0.9, 1.1, length = 10000)
ll(sq)
```

gives one output and along with that:

```
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

The warnings are:

```
 In o[i] <- o[i] + exp(b) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

The same warning is repeated.

I don't understand the issue. Isn't it the case that when you pass a vector, it just takes each element one by one one passes it into the function. Then, if the function is working fine with a single input, there shouldn't be a problem.

EDIT:

Here is the data generated for `a`, `d` and `cox.fit`

```
RNGkind(sample.kind = "Rejection")
set.seed(8756) 
#     Generate sample A times with censoring
#
library(survival)
#
#
LenA <- 200
TimeA <- c(sort(round(runif(10,1,364),4)),rep(365,LenA-10))
CensorA <- c(rbinom(10,1,0.8),rep(0,LenA-10))
#
#     Generate sample B times with censoring
#
LenB <- 100
TimeB <- c(sort(round(runif(10,1,364),4)),rep(365,LenB-10))
CensorB <- c(rbinom(10,1,0.8),rep(0,LenB-10))
#
#     Combine data
#
Time <- c(TimeA, TimeB)
Censor <- c(CensorA, CensorB)
Group <- factor(c(rep(1,LenA), rep(2,LenB)))

a = cbind(Time,Censor,Group)

#Surv object:

library(survival)
Surv(Time, Censor)
km.surv <- survfit(Surv(Time, Censor) ~ 1, conf.type = "plain")
summary(km.surv)

#Cox Fit:
cox.fit <- coxph(Surv(Time, Censor) ~ Group)
summary(cox.fit)

d = km.surv$time[km.surv$n.event==1]
```

Edit:

Its working fine when I do it like this:

```
k = numeric(10000)
for (i in 1:10000){
  k[i] = ll(sq[i])
}

k
```

Comment: Can you provide examples of `d` and `a` so we can recreate your issue?

Comment: Can you provide the data needed to understand your function? ie, `dput(d)`, `dput(a)` and `cox.fit$coefficients`.

Comment: You ask: " Isn't it the case that when you pass a vector, it just takes each element one by one one passes it into the function." and the answer is no. That's not how R functions handle arguments.